# how can i save the file after SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, into-outfile

i use this query to dump table into csv file :

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
        FROM tableName";
```

i get a result.csv file in the db folder of mysql

how can i save it at root of my site ?

Answer (score 1):

In place of `result.csv` provide the path where you want it to be saved:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/your/site/result.csv'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
        FROM tableName";
```

Comment: The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement is intended primarily to let you very quickly dump a table to a text file on the server machine. If you want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server host, you normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file system.

However, if the MySQL client software is installed on the remote machine, you can instead use a client command such as mysql -e "SELECT ..." > file_name to generate the file on the client host.

Comment: MySQL should have write permission to the path where you want to save this file. If it is absolutely necessary, start mysql with user=root line in the my.cnf and run the same command.

Answer (score 0):

this code can export mysql table into csv file , i've tested it with large table

```
<?php 
// tested with success
$db_name     = "db_name";
$db_password = "pass";
$db_link     = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

$table = "table_name";

function assoc_query_2D($sql, $id_name = false){
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  if($result){
    if($id_name == false){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $arr[] = $row;
    }else{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $arr[$id] = $row;
      }
    }
  }else
      return 0;

  return $arr;
}

function query_whole_table($table, $value = '*'){
    $sql = "SELECT $value FROM $table";
  return assoc_query_2D($sql);
}

$export_str = "";
$result = query_whole_table($table);

foreach($result as $record){
  $export_str .= implode(";",$record) . "\n";
}
// add time to fileName
$date = time(); 
// output the file 
// we can set a header to send it directly to the browser
file_put_contents($date.'_'.$table."_export.csv", $export_str);
?>
```